# Error when training model by using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train my custom object by using tensorflow, however, when I run following command it shows an error with protobuf:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py", line 1152, in ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber
     raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result) 
 google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 235:1 : Expected identifier or number, got <.
```

I am using following command to run train.py:

```
python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

[image: train.py]

I am a beginner in this topic, so I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please embed any code in your question rather than provide a link to it (most SO users won't follow links).  Also, you might want to add the exact error you are getting.